# .NET ShortcutKeys on ToolStripMenuItem in main Form doesn't work when other Form is active

Tags: c#

I have an application (.NET / C#) with a main Form and two optional tool/property Forms. The main Form has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> set as ShortcutKeys for File->Save. When the main Form is active, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> works fine, but when one of the other Forms is active it doesn't work. 
This setup in an application is so common, I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I just can't find it.

Regards, 
Håkan Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to do sending old form reference to currently active form. For ex.

This is your old form : OldForm;

This is your active form : ActiveForm;

Make your ActiveForm opening with parameter like:

```
//This is global variable;

public OldForm frm;

public ActiveForm()

{

InitializeComponents();

}


public ActiveForm(OldForm myOldForm)

{

InitializeComponents();

frm = myOldForm;// at this point you got your OldForm !

}
```

So now, you can handle your old form from your activeform. You can reach everyControl of your OldFrom with using your frm variable. I hope this answer can you give you any idea.